# Using DJI Onboard SDK to monitor C1/C2 buttons on hand controller

Tags: dji-sdk

Can't find out how to use the DJI OnboardSDK to check status or monitor the custom hand controller buttons C1/C2.

There has got to be a way to do this.  Using the M100 UAV, which is the developer platform.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this directly using the Onboard SDK. A possible workaround might be to use the Mobile SDK to monitor those buttons, and communicate their status to the Onboard SDK using [Data Transparent Transmission](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/data-transparent-transmission.html) - see the Ping ADS-B [sample](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sensor-integration-guides/ping/README.html) app for a working implementation of Data Transparent Transmission.

Answer (score 0):

This is old post,

At 2 years ago with Osdk 3.2 it is not possible.

In latest release 3.8/3.8.1 with latest firmware 1.7.7, it is possible to get all button working.

I tested with C1 C2 Shoot and couple roller on the lightbridge-2 controller in this week.

For DJI Cendence or DJI New Smart Controller, I haven`t tested it yet.

Comment: How did you manage to do this? I'm trying to do something similar with the M300, but the OSDK documentation is really sparse and I can't figure out how to do it.